# jQuery: How can I disable a select option if value is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site that outputs something similar to:

```
<select id="tinynav1" class="tinynav tinynav1"> 
<option value="http://google.com">Home</option> 
<option value="undefined">About</option> 
<option value="http://website.com">- School News</option>
<option value="http://etc.com">- History Of The School</option>
<option value="http://etc.com">- Contact Us</option>
<option value="undefined">Curriculum</option>
<option value="http://etc.com">- Our Mission</option>
</select>
```

I want to loop through the values, and if the value is undefined I want to add the attribute disabled i.e., the output will be

```
<select id="tinynav1" class="tinynav tinynav1"> 
<option value="http://google.com">Home</option> 
<option value="undefined" disabled="disabled">About</option> 
<option value="http://website.com">- School News</option>
<option value="http://etc.com">- History Of The School</option>
<option value="http://etc.com">- Contact Us</option>
<option value="undefined" disabled="disabled">Curriculum</option>
<option value="http://etc.com">- Our Mission</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very simple option for jQuery.

```js
$("#tinynav1 option[value='undefined']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="tinynav1" class="tinynav tinynav1"> 
  <option value="http://google.com">Home</option> 
  <option value="undefined" disabled="disabled">About</option> 
  <option value="http://website.com">- School News</option>
  <option value="http://etc.com">- History Of The School</option>
  <option value="http://etc.com">- Contact Us</option>
  <option value="undefined" disabled="disabled">Curriculum</option>
  <option value="http://etc.com">- Our Mission</option>
</select>
```

Here's a pure JavaScript option if you don't want to use jQuery:

```js
        var select = document.getElementById("tinynav1");
        for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
            if (select.options[i].value === "undefined"){
                select.options[i].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        }
```

```html
<select id="tinynav1" class="tinynav tinynav1"> 
  <option value="http://google.com">Home</option> 
  <option value="undefined" disabled="disabled">About</option> 
  <option value="http://website.com">- School News</option>
  <option value="http://etc.com">- History Of The School</option>
  <option value="http://etc.com">- Contact Us</option>
  <option value="undefined" disabled="disabled">Curriculum</option>
  <option value="http://etc.com">- Our Mission</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough with the attribute selector :

```
$("option[value=undefined]").prop('disabled', true);
```

- [`[attribute=value]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)
- [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

---

## Edit

Since the vanilla JS seems important, here a vanilla JS solution :

```
var options = document.getElementById('tinynav1').options;

for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
    options[i].disabled = options[i].value === 'undefined';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternativelly to the other jQuery's answers... you can go with pure Javascript:

```js
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

document.querySelectorAll("#tinynav1 option[value='undefined']").forEach(function(item){
    item.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

```html
<select id="tinynav1" class="tinynav tinynav1"> 
<option value="http://google.com">Home</option> 
<option value="undefined">About</option> 
<option value="http://website.com">- School News</option>
<option value="http://etc.com">- History Of The School</option>
<option value="http://etc.com">- Contact Us</option>
<option value="undefined">Curriculum</option>
<option value="http://etc.com">- Our Mission</option>
</select>
```